# If $\sin\alpha+\sin\gamma=2\sin\beta$, prove $\tan\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}+\tan\frac{\beta+\gamma}{2}=2\tan\frac{\gamma+\alpha}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

> If
> $$
> \sin\alpha+ \sin\gamma = 2\sin\beta  
> $$
> Prove that
> $$
> \tan\frac{\alpha+ \beta}{2}+ \tan\frac{\beta+ \gamma}{2} = 2 \tan\frac{\gamma+ \alpha}{2}  
> $$

Me and my teacher already tried so many times, but just got stuck every time no matter using sum to product or trying to change all the tangent into sin/cos.

---

My work:

I tried

$$
\sin\alpha -\: sin\:\beta+ \sin\gamma - sin\:\beta= 0 \\ 
\\
\cos\frac{\alpha+ \beta}{2} \sin\frac{\alpha- \beta}{2} + \cos\frac{\gamma+ \beta}{2} \sin\frac{\gamma- \beta}{2}= 0 
$$
but it seems useless for proving the identities

and then I try to change the prove  into

$$
\frac{\sin\frac{\alpha+ \beta}{2}}{\cos\frac{\alpha+ \beta}{2}}+ \frac{\sin\frac{\beta+ \gamma}{2}}{\cos\frac{\beta+ \gamma}{2}}  = \frac{2\sin\frac{\gamma+ \alpha}{2}}{\cos\frac{\gamma+ \alpha}{2}}
$$

and it still have no clues to do.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @narip how  For $alpha=gamma=π/6  $         and $beta=pi/2 $   LHS= 1 but RHS =2

Comment: @narip may not have noticed the factor of $2$ on the first equation's RHS.

Comment: Hint: Write the first equation as 
$$\sin\alpha-\sin\beta=\sin\beta-\sin\gamma$$
and apply the difference-to-product identity. (What you've tried is essentially this, but I find that having the terms on opposite sides of the equation is helpful.) Rewrite the second equation similarly and see if you can manipulate it into a form that follows from the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

Set $a = (\alpha + \beta)/2$, $b = (\beta + \gamma)/2$ and $c = (\alpha + \gamma)/2$. Then $\alpha = a - b + c$, $\beta = a + b - c$ and $\gamma = -a + b + c$.

With this substitution and applying the sum and difference identities, the first equation becomes

$$
2\cos(a) \cos(b) \sin(c) + 2\sin(a)\sin(b)\sin(c) = -2\cos(a)\cos(b)\sin(c) + 2\cos(a)\sin(b)\cos(c) + 2\sin(a)\cos(b)\cos(c) + 2\sin(a)\sin(b)\sin(c).
$$

Dividing both sides by 2 and grouping like terms, we have

$$
2\cos(a) \cos(b) \sin(c) = \cos(a)\sin(b)\cos(c) + \sin(a)\cos(b)\cos(c).
$$

Finally, dividing both sides of the equation by $\cos(a)\cos(b)\cos(c)$, we get $2\tan(c) = \tan(b) + \tan(a)$, which is the desired equation.